# Getting N x N matrix determinant in C

Tags: c, matrix, logic, determinants

I've been trying to compute an N x N matrix determinant, so that this is what I've got so far. The result of if it's `-378029970`. I don't know what is going on because if I change the N value for the matrix size it works fine and prints the right result which is `-20`. I debugged the whole script and found out the problem is when I change the N value. I'm kind new in C language so I appreciate if you could give me a hand with it. Thanks!

```
void getCofactor(int q, int n, int matrix[][n], int temp[][n]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int p = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            if (row != p && col != q) {
                temp[i][j++] = matrix[row][col];
                if (j == n - 1) {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int determinante(int n, int matrix[][n]) {
    int D = 0;

    if (n == 1) {
        return matrix[0][0];
    }

    int temp[n][n];
    int sign = 1;

    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        getCofactor(f, n, matrix, temp);

        D += sign * matrix[0][f] * determinante(n - 1, temp);

        sign = -sign;
    }
    return D;
}

int main() {

    int matrix[3][3] = { { 3, -2, 5}, { -2, 8, 10}, { 3, -2, 4 }};
    int LINHA = 3;

    printf("Determinante: %d", determinante(LINHA, matrix));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: I thought It would be useful for c++ learners as well.

Comment: In `getCofactor()` the array `temp` has the same row width as `matrix` but you don't increment its indexing unless the condition is met. How will the caller know how many rows in `temp` to use? Note that unused elements in `int temp[n][n];` have not been initialised.

Comment: I thought It was already initialized, because I'm passing "LINHA" as a parameter so that I assumed that N would carry the LINHA value which is three in this case.

Comment: `int temp[n][n];` is not initialised. Are you expecting unwritten elements to be `0`? And are the `j` and `i` increments supposed to be *outside* the code block with the conditional write to `temp`?

Comment: @RafaelRossales In general, you solve things very differently in C and C++

Comment: When `determinante()` recurses, it passes the array `temp` to itself as the argument `matrix`. This gets passed to `getCofactor()` which examines every element, however not every element of the array `temp` has been set to something.

Comment: The logic from getCofactor() seems to be right because it works perfectly when I change the N value in the function calling  `getCofactor(f, N, matrix, temp);`. I think the problem might be in the function initialization as you mentioned before.

Comment: @klutt sorry, I just thought It would be useful.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the unused elements of `temp` are not a problem, the incompatible dimensions in the call `determinante(n - 1, temp)` produce the incorrect result. The behavior is undefined and this bug is difficult for the compiler to detect.

Comment: @chqrlie so there are no unused elements: one row and one column are skipped.

Comment: @WeatherVane: exactly! but the code in the question would store this `n-1` by `n-1` matrix at the top-left of `temp`, leaving the last column and the last row uninitialized. This was not a problem is the matrix geometry was fixed by making `N` global. C99 VLAs are error prone and 2D VLAs should be banned or implemented with a different scheme where the dimensions are part of the structure, not a separate argument.

Comment: @RafaelRossales Don't worry. It's a common beginner mistake here. In general, we treat C and C++ as two completely different languages. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `temp` is defined as `int temp[n][n]` but this matrix' dimensions are incompatible when passed to `determinante(n - 1, temp)`.

You should modify the definition of `temp` to reduce the size and modify the prototype of `getCofactor` to reflect the actual dimensions of `matrix` and `temp`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getCofactor(int q, int n, int matrix[][n], int temp[][n - 1]) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int p = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            if (row != p && col != q) {
                temp[i][j++] = matrix[row][col];
                if (j == n - 1) {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int determinante(int n, int matrix[][n]) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return matrix[0][0];
    }

    int temp[n - 1][n - 1];
    int sign = 1;
    int D = 0;

    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        getCofactor(f, n, matrix, temp);
        D += sign * matrix[0][f] * determinante(n - 1, temp);
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return D;
}

int main() {
    int matrix[3][3] = { { 3, -2, 5}, { -2, 8, 10}, { 3, -2, 4 } };
    int LINHA = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]);

    printf("Determinante: %d\n", determinante(LINHA, matrix));
    return 0;
}
```